# How to "Add a new data source" in a WPF Core application?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, wpf-core

**Question:** How to "Add a new data source" in a WPF Core application?
 
I performed:
 - Created a WPF Core application;
 - Added the class `CntDBSchool`;
 - Added the class `Student`;
 - Menu `Project` //" Add a new data source ";
 - Result: there is no class `Student`;
 
[image]

[image]

**Class `CntDBSchool`.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 
namespace WpfApp.Models
{
    class CntDBSchool: DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet <Student> Student {get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Class `Student`.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
 
namespace WpfApp.Models
{
    class Student
    {
        public int StudentID {get; set; }
        public string StudentName {get; set; }
        public Nullable <int> StandardId {get; set; }
        public byte [] RowVersion {get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Table `Student`.**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo]. [Student] (
  [StudentID] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
  [StudentName] varchar (50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
  [StandardId] int NULL,
  [RowVersion] timestamp NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentID])
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON [PRIMARY],
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_Standard] FOREIGN KEY ([StandardId]) REFERENCES [dbo]. [Standard] ([StandardId]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I do the same in the WPF Framework application, the Student class is present in the Add New Data Source window.
I do:
 - Created a WPF Framework application;
 - Created `Model ADO.NET EDM`;
 - In the file `DBModel.tt` replaced:
 - - line - 296 replaced `ICollection` with`ObservableCollection`;
 - - line - 484 replaced `ICollection` with`ObservableCollection`;
 - - line - 51 replaced `HashSet` with`ObservableCollection`;
 - - lines - 431 replaced `System.Collections.Generic` with`System.Collections.ObjectModel`;
 - Menu `Project` //" Add a new data source ";
 - Result: the class `Student` is present;
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us how you're adding the Datasource in your first screenshot with all the steps.

Comment: @Train Sorry, I do not understand your question.
I think I described everything in steps.
I have nothing more to add.
If it’s not difficult for you, describe your requirements in more detail. Maybe you have the opportunity to give an example.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this today too.  Adding A datasource with a WPF Framework application works but adding a datasource with WPF Core application doesn't work.  I found that someone submitted an issue back in July of 19'  https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1196.  They racked it up to not all features work with core.